# Trying to set TemplateUrl conditionally using a given attribute (Angular)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, binding

I'm trying to use a different `templateUrl` depending on the value of a variable in my controller, but I am having trouble binding these variables. I have been trying to do this in the link function, not sure if there is an easier way. Firstly, here's my HTML:

```
<div po-generic-notification title='errorModal.title' error-list="errorModal.errorList" type="mostRecentError.type" message="mostRecentError.message" error="mostRecentError.message"></div>
```

This triggers the following directive (a bit of a work in progress at this stage...):

```
.directive('poGenericNotification', function($compile) {
  var openFuncNameErm = 'openErm';
  return {
    controller: 'ErmModalCtrl',
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      title: '=',
      errorList: '=',
      type: '=',
      message: '='
    },
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log(attrs.type);
      if (attrs.type==="Alert") {
        templateUrl: 'src/alerts/templates/error-alert.html';
        error: attrs.message;
      }
      else if (attrs.type==="Info") {
        templateUrl: 'src/alerts/templates/info-alert.html';
        info: attrs.message;
      }
      error: attrs.message; //temporary
      element.removeAttr('po-generic-notification'); // necessary to avoid infinite compile loop
      var ngClick;
      if (attrs.before) {
        ngClick = attrs.ngClick ? openFuncNameErm + '()' + '; ' + attrs.ngClick : openFuncNameErm + '()';
      }
      else {
        ngClick = attrs.ngClick ? attrs.ngClick + '; ' + openFuncNameErm + '()' : openFuncNameErm + '()';
      }
      element.attr('ng-click', ngClick);
      $compile(element[0])(scope);
    }
  }
})
```

You can see in my link function I have tried to conditionally set the `templateUrl` depending on the value of `attrs.type`. The result of the `console.log` is `mostRecentError.type` rather than the value from the controller. Here is my controller:

```
.controller('ErrorModalCtrl', ['errorHandler', '$scope', function (errorHandler, $scope) {
    $scope.errorModal = {
        title: 'Notification Centre',
        errorList: []
    };
    $scope.mostRecentError = {
      type:'', message: '', timestamp: ''
    };
    $scope.addError = function(type, message) {
        errorHandler.addError(type, message);
        $scope.mostRecentError = errorHandler[0];
    };
    $scope.errorModal.errorList = errorHandler;
}]);
```

Is this the right approach? Why is my `attrs.type` value literal, rather than a reference to the controller?

Thanks

Comment: attributes are always read as literal as opposed to passing them to scope where they are evaluated from parent scope

Answer (score 0):

You have the scope set so just use that instead of attrs:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    if (scope.type === 'Alert') {...}
}
```

I would also advise just passing the entire errorMsg one time:

```
scope: { errMsg: '='}
```

then in your html:

```
<div po-generic-notification title='errorModal.title' error-list="errorModal.errorList" err-msg="mostRecentError"div>
```

then in  your link function you can access them like:

```
scope.errMsg.type;
scope.errMsg.message;
scope.errMsg.error;
```

Comment: Interesting....this gives me access to the values in my `mostRecentError` object on initiation. Problem is, these values change and I want these to be updated as time goes on. Is the link function only compiled once? If so, what would be the way round this?

Comment: Your scope values should update whenever the mostRecentError Object changes. Make sure you are changing it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To get different templates by a passed attribute, in the directive declaration you can simply write:

```
return {
    scope:{},
    templateUrl: function(element,attrs){
         if (attrs.type==="Alert") {
             return 'src/alerts/templates/error-alert.html';
         else if (attrs.type==="Info") {
             return 'src/alerts/templates/info-alert.html';
         }
    }
    link: function(){
        // ...
    }
};
```

When you access attributes via `attrs`, they are simply set of strings. If you access them from isolated scope(scope:{}) or scope.$eval(), that is when the attribute value gets evaluated and converted to a value or reference to the parent controller.

Comment: But if as you say `attrs.type` does not evaluate to the value, how do you access the actual value? I tried passing `scope` into the function and using `scope.type` but this returned an undefined value.